# looking for a quick and light storage solution for php - simpleXML?

Tags: php, simplexml

i want to use simplexml & a webform to capture some simple information but i'm worried that if someone submits the form at precisely the same moment i might lose some data.

how can i ensure this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind those users waiting for eachother you could implement a simple lock using [`flock`](https://www.php.net/flock). Anything more complex will require a database of some sorts to ensure atomicity.